# SwiftUI concatenate Text and Text Alignment

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to concatenate two strings and then have the final result center aligned.  The issue seems to be that two `Text()` views combined with + no longer create a `Text()` type.  Attempting to apply any `.multiLineTextAlignment` or just `Alignment` gives the error

Cannot convert value of type `some View` to expected argument type `Text`

Heres an example:

```swift
Text(myText ?? "")
    .font(Font(myFont))
    .kerning(spacing)
    .foregroundColor(Color(textColor))
//.multilineTextAlignment(.center) - throws error
+ Text(text2 ?? "")
    .font(Font(myFont))
    .foregroundColor(Color(textColor))
    .baselineOffset(6)
    .kerning(spacing)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're absolute right that you can not concatenate `Text()` when one is using `.multiLineTextAlignment`.

In theory, what you've written would create a Text view that wraps until reaching a specific line and then no longer wraps. This is not a supported behavior in SwiftUI and would need to be built custom. All concatenated Text views need to generally follow the same alignment rules.

However, if you are wanting to apply the same alignment rules to all concatenated Text views you can easily do that by wrapping them in a `Group()` like so:

```
Group {
    Text(myText ?? "")
        .font(Font(myFont))
        .kerning(spacing)
        .foregroundColor(Color(textColor))
    + Text(text2 ?? "")
        .font(Font(myFont))
        .foregroundColor(Color(textColor))
        .baselineOffset(6)
        .kerning(spacing)
}
.multilineTextAlignment(.center)
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to center the text horizontally, don't use the `+` operator. If your text has the same style, interpolate the String, like this: `Text("\(myText ?? "")\(text2 ?? "")")`. Otherwise, try using a `HStack` and center that within your parent view. You can adjust the `spacing` property of the HStack to make it look more natural.

````swift
HStack(spacing: 1) {
    Text(myText ?? "")
        .font(Font(myFont))
        .kerning(spacing)
        .foregroundColor(Color(textColor))
    Text(text2 ?? "")
        .font(Font(myFont))
        .foregroundColor(Color(textColor))
        .baselineOffset(6)
        .kerning(spacing)```
}
````

Comment: The text doesn't have the same style.  The second text is smaller and offset.  Setting an alignment on HStack doesn't seem to have any effect on the textAlignment itself.  the Text is centered within the stack, but its still left aligned.

Comment: @JMD what block do you have containing the `HStack`? When just placed in a `VStack`, it centers as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like surrounding the Text + Text inside a stack, then applying the .multiLineText to the stack itself is the solution.